# How to get largest number from Firebase datalist

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, integer

I'm using Firebase database and I have a lot of nodes and every node has a different and unique number [image: image of database]

This is the code I'm using to retrieve `Id's`

```
for (DataSnapshot homework : homeworkChildren) {
                    NewsModel c = homework.getValue(NewsModel.class);
                    Log.e("MAX_VALU", String.valueOf(c.getId()));
                }
```

[image: This is] what my `c.getId()` returning me

**And I want only one maximum id from all Id's**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you can use the following lines of code:

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot homework : homeworkChildren) {
    NewsModel c = homework.getValue(NewsModel.class);
    ids.add(c.getId());
}
int max = Collections.max(ids);
Log.e("MAX_VALU", String.valueOf(max));
```

According to your example, the result in your logcat will be:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable at the top.
`var max = 0`.
Make sure your `c.getId()` never returns `0`.

Now inside the for loop, you can do something like this.

```
for(DataSnapshot homework : homeworkChildren){
  NewsModel c = homework.getValue(NewsModel.class);
  if(max == 0) {
  max = c.getId() 
  } else {
  if(max <= c.getId()) 
  max = c.getId()  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `ids` are in the form of a pattern for each news like (1,2,3,4,5......).

Do this:

```
........
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

//get the total number of children from the main dataSnapshot:
int totalItems = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

//now loop like you did
for (DataSnapshot homework : homeworkChildren) {
NewsModel c = homework.getValue(NewsModel.class);

if(c.getId() == totalItems){
//this is the max
Log.e("MAX_VALU", String.valueOf(c.getId()));
}

}
```